# Filtering data - REST <RSS>

Tags: xml, rest, rss

I wonder if anyone can help me filter this data in some way?

Here is [a link to the data](http://www.nen.gov.uk/rest/tandl/list/title/asc).

I'd like to create a web page to display this data but also filter it in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if using PHP, start with this:

```
<?PHP
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://tinyurl.com/mykv85');
    print_r($xml);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read it with some kind of [RSS Library](http://wiki.python.org/moin/RssLibraries) (such as Feedparser).

Iterate through the items, filtering as required.

Display the results.

```
import feedparser

feed = feedparser.parse( "http://tinyurl.com/mykv85" )

for item in feed["items"]:
    if "foo" in item["title"]:
        print item["summary"]
```